Why has this question been closed by the Community Bot?
Why are the following question and its answers deleted by Community Bot?

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/112528/is-an-explanation-for-consciousness-even-possible-if-not-what-are-we-searching

Who is controlling the "Community Bot"? Which criterion has been applied in the present case?

Does this answer your question? Why are so many upvoted questions with upvoted answers being deleted recently?

It's happening with a bunch of questions: Why are so many upvoted questions with upvoted answers being deleted recently? - that question also has an answer from a mod now. I also voted to undelete the specific question mentioned here (although I might be a bit biased, given the extended answer I posted to it).

The question has now been undeleted.

... and it's been deleted again by a mod (which seems like a questionable use of mod powers, but I don't really feel like fighting that battle).

It was deleted by the community bot due to the issues described in other meta threads. It was (erroneously) undeleted by Geoffrey when he seemingly confused two different meta discussions and re-deleted by me exactly because of what I described here.
I won't reward breaking the rules nor allow for this kind of spamming the same questions in different guises again and again.
